# I can not update an item list in the database room and add the item to the favorites list

Tags: database, sqlite, android-room, favorites

****I can not set an isfavorites value by clicking Add to Favorites .****
**Android Studio displays a null pointer exception for ringTonesDao .
I do not know how to fix this error.
On the other hand, because ringTonesDao is an interface, if I set its value to new RingTonesDao, I have to set all its functions.**

***this is RingTonesAdapter***

```
//Imports and Package name
public class RingTonesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RingTonesAdapter.ringTonesViewHolder> {
private List<RingTones> ringTonesList;
RingTonesDao ringTonesDao; //  <--This is null in logcat


public RingTonesAdapter(List<RingTones> ringTonesList) {
    this.ringTonesList = ringTonesList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ringTonesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.actv_main_list, 
 parent, false);
    return new ringTonesViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ringTonesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Set RingTone name to TextView
    //Set RingTone Btn
    //Set Alarm Btn
    //Set Notification Btn
    //Add To Favorites Btn

    if (ringTonesList.get(position).isFavorite()) {
        holder.btn_addToFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorites);
    } else {
        holder.btn_addToFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_addtofavorites);
    }
   

   holder.btn_addToFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Long id = ringTonesList.get(position).getId();
                ringTonesDao.update(true,id);
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Null Pointer 
     Exception",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    //Set Play Btn

    //ringTonesViewHolder and count items
```

***and this is RingTonesDao***

```
//import and package

 @Dao
 public interface RingTonesDao {

@Insert
Long add(RingTones ringTones);

@Delete
int delete(RingTones ringTones);

@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ringtones")
List<RingTones> getRingTones();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ringtones WHERE favorites>0 ")
List<RingTones> favorites();

@Query("DELETE FROM tbl_ringtones")
void deleteAll();

@Query("UPDATE tbl_ringtones SET favorites=:favorites WHERE id=:id")
int update (Boolean favorites ,Long id);

 }
```

Comment: images:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMoky.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJWlo.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJNEw.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxAK2.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dWKB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
DatabaseClient.getInstance(v.getContext()).getAppDatabase()
                    .RingTonesDao()
                    .update(true,id);
```

read more how to use Rom database : [from this example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/)

also there is a difference between Boolean and boolean in Java, 

in your case try to use `boolean` instead `Boolean` in your update function.

Comment: I did this but the problem was not solved

Comment: see the update of my answer

Comment: I'm a novice programmer and I do not know exactly where and how to write the code you said

Comment: Thank you for your guidance . Solved my problem.

Comment: I wrote: ringTonesDao = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase (v.getContext ())
                             .getRingtonesDao ();
                     long id = ringTonesList.get (position) .getId ();
                     ringTonesDao.update (true, id);